# How to split list to lists by condition?

Tags: python

I want split a list into multiple lists, based on a condition. If the difference in the series grows more than 4, then it is trigger to split the list till that item from last split item.

For example:

```
in = [1,2,3,9,10,11,100,200]
out = [ [1,2,3 ], [ 9,10,11 ], [100], [200]  ]
```

by condition

```
If (next - prev) > 4
```

Comment: Can you show what you tried so far? Maybe you were really close and an extra set of eyes might help you find that small mistake you're making?

Comment: What are `next` and `prev` supposed to be? how does that condition create that output?

Comment: Given your condition, one would expect: `[..., [100], [200]]`

Comment: Shouldn't `100` and `200` be in two separate lists since 200 - 100 > 4?

Answer (score 3):

```
def splitlist(L):
    if not L: return []
    answer = [[L[0]]]

    for i in L[1:]:
        if i - answer[-1][-1] < 4:
            answer[-1].append(i)
        else:
            answer.append([i])
    return answer
```

Output:

```
In [112]: splitlist([1,2,3,9,10,11,100,200])
Out[112]: [[1, 2, 3], [9, 10, 11], [100], [200]]
```

Answer (score 3):

Short solution using `numpy` module:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([1,2,3,9,10,11,100,200])
out = [a.tolist() for a in np.split(arr, np.where(np.diff(arr) > 4)[0]+1)]
print(out)
```

The output:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [9, 10, 11], [100], [200]]
```

---

- `np.where(np.diff(arr) > 4)` - find the array indices where condition *"difference between next value and previous value is greater than 4"* is met
- `np.split(x, indices)` - split the initial array by crucial indices

Comment: Liked the numpy approach.

Answer (score 2):

NOTICE: *in* and *next* are Python keywords and builtin functions respectively.

The trick is to use `zip()` function with 2 slices of the same list, but shifted on one item:

```
in_list = [1, 2, 3, 9, 10, 11, 100, 200]

parts = [[]]
for prev_item, next_item in zip(in_list[:-1], in_list[1:]):
    top = parts[-1]
    top.append(prev_item)
    if next_item - prev_item > 4:
        parts.append([])
top = parts[-1]
top.append(in_list[-1])
```

The output is:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [9, 10, 11], [100], [200]]
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible approaches:

```
ls = [1,2,3,9,10,11,100,200, 201, 209]

#output list
output = list()
startind = 0

for ind, val in enumerate(ls):
    if ls[ind]-ls[ind-1] > 4:
        output.append(ls[startind:ind])
        startind = ind

# appending the left over from last detected difference of 4
output.append(ls[startind:])
print output
```

Output: [[1, 2, 3], [9, 10, 11], [100], [200, 201], [209]]